# How to convert a function to a lens getter?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Probably related to [What in lens should I use to build a read-only getter by index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39311908/what-in-lens-should-i-use-to-build-a-read-only-getter-by-index)

I'm looking for a variant of the [lens function](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.1/lens-4.16.1/Control-Lens-Combinators.html#v:lens) that allows me to build a [`Getter s a`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.1/lens-4.16.1/Control-Lens-Combinators.html#t:Getter) from an `s -> a`. Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`to`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.1/lens-4.16.1/Control-Lens-Getter.html#v:to), which "build[s] an (index-preserving) `Getter` from an arbitrary Haskell function".